# How to define globally serialization date in lavarel?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, date, serialization

Something good with laravel is "$casts" attribute. Exemple with dates :

```
protected $casts = [
    'date_rec'      => 'datetime:Y-m-d',
    'date_liv'      => 'datetime:Y-m-d',
];
```

It works well if you return result of eloquent's query.

But if you don't want return full object with all relations it's the hell.
Examples :

```
protected $casts = [
    'date_rec'      => 'datetime:Y-m-d',
    'date_liv'      => 'datetime:Y-m-d',
];

public function asListItem()
{
    return [
        "try_1" => $this->date_rec,                      // return : "2021-10-19T22:00:00.000000Z"
        "try_2" => $this->date_rec->format('Y-m-d'),     // return : "2021-10-19" or error/crash if date is null
        "try_3" => substr($this->date_rec ?? '', 0, 10), // work always but boring
        "try_4" => json_encode($this->date_rec)          // infinite loading and then error timeout
    ];
}
```

Is it possible to define how I want laravel parse date globally at serialization ?
Thx

Comment: Can you please more elaborate so can help you? Exactly not getting what you did and what you want.

Comment: Why not you check null in your ```try_2``` like this ```$this->date_rec ?? $this->date_rec->format('Y-m-d')```

Comment: See [ask] please, because this possibly wins a prize for the vaguest question title ever. And the description isn't very clear either - "it's the hell" isn't an error message or a useful problem description.

Comment: I would like "try_1" work as expected with "$casts" attribute or other global declaration. "$casts" works well only if we return the full object. Not a custom array or properties

Comment: @AnisurRahman your proposal will return the "try_1" if date_rec is not null and generate an error if date_rec is null. Anyway my wish is to use the more simple expression possible -> $this->date_rec. I define "$casts" for that raison. But laravel dont care in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Carbon::setToStringFormat('your format');` in your provider to set a default string format